# How to count duplicates in two unsorted arrays

Tags: java, arrays, testing, count, duplicates

I need to compare the guess and code arrays and count the number of correct digits in the guess.

It works until there are duplicate numbers in the code array. I know it's something to do with the second for loop and subtracting from the correctDigits.

```java
public static int digits(int[] code, int[] guess) {
    int digits = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < guess.length; j++) {
            if (guess[j] == code[i]) {
                digits++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < code.length; j++) {
            if (code[i] == code[j] && code[i] != guess[j] && code[j] != guess[i]) {
                digits--;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return digits;
}
```

Comment: So all you're after is whether the arrays have the same number of digits no matter where they are, i.e. `[1,2,3,4]` and `[4,3,2,1]` would have 4 digits in common?

Comment: @Thomas yes! I have another method that counts the correct placement separately and that one doesn't have any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned "only using loops and basic knowledge" I assume concepts like maps are not included here and "basic knowledge" means "arrays".

If all you need to know is the number of digits try to convert your input to a 10-element array of counts, i.e. each digit would be the input.

Example:

```
int[] codeDigits = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
   codeDigits[code[i]]++;
}
```

This would turn `[5,9,9,9]` into `[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3]`, i.e. 5: 1x, 9: 3x

Now do this for the guess as well, e.g. `[0,0,9,9]` becomes `[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2]`.

Now all you have to do is count the number of digits:

```
int counter = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < codeDigits.length; i++ ) {
  if( codeDigits[i] >= guessDigits[i] ) {
    counter += guessDigits[i]; //guessed the exact number or less -> use the guess
  } else {
     counter += codeDigits[i]; //guessed more -> use the code
  }
}
```

If you are able to use a `Math` function then the loop body could be replaced by `counter += Math.min(codeDigits[i], guessDigits[i]);`.

One more illustration (with longer codes to illustrate better):

```
 code: [5,0,9,9,1,7,1]   ->   [1,2,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,2]
guess: [9,9,0,9,7,4,2]   ->   [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,3]
-----------------------------------------
minimum of each digit:         1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2
```

If you sum those minimums you get 4 correct digits: 1x 0, 1x 7, 2x 9

Comment: That's brilliant, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate two Maps from these arrays, which associating a Value with its number of occurrences.

Then iterate over the entries of the Map obtained from the `code` array and compare its *values* with the corresponding *values* from the Map created based on the `guess` array. That would allow determining the number of correct/incorrect guesses.

Comment: I don't know how to use Maps and couldn't use it in a project, but thank you

Comment: @cymru_yesac In case if the numbers in these arrays are bounded (let's say they are in range `[0,1000]`) the same logic can be implemented using arrays only.

Answer (score 0):

there are several solutions. one of them is indexing duplicated values of code array, then check them at first loop (and remove the 2nd loop):

```
int correctDigits = 0;
int[] duplicateIndexes = new int[code.length];
for (int i=0; i < code.length; i++) {
    if( duplicateIndexes[i] == 1) continue;
    for (int j=0; j < code.length; j++) {
        if( core[i] == core[j]) {
             duplicateIndexes[j] == 1;
             continue;
        }
    }
 }

for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
    if (duplicatedIndexes[i] == 1) continue;
    for (int j = 0; j < guess.length; j++) {
        if (guess[j] == code[i]) {
            correctDigits++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work.

**Code**

```
     public static int getCorrectDigits(int[] code, int[] guess) {
    if (code.length != guess.length) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different lengths");
    }
    
    int correctDigits = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {  
            if (guess[i] == code[i]) {
                correctDigits++;
        }
    }

    return correctDigits;
}
```

**Output**

```
Code - 5 9 9 9
Guess - 0 9 9 9
Passes - 3

Code - 5 9 9 9
Guess - 9 9 0 0
Passes - 1

Code - 5 9 9 9
Guess - 0 0 9 9
Passes - 2

Code - 5 9 9 9
Guess - 9 0 0 0
Passes - 0
```

Comment: "I hope this will work." - If you're not sure it works you might want not to post it. I'd at least add some explanation of how the code is supposed to work :)

Comment: Also note that that `5 9 9 9 vs 9 9 0 0` should return 2 and `5 9 9 9 vs 9 0 0 0`  should return 1 as per the OP's example, i.e. the location of the digits isn't relevant here (`9 9 0 0 vs. 0 0 9 9` should return 4).

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd join in on the fun - maintain a boolean array of `code` digits used, requires only one nested loop and reverse the looping order:

```
public static int getCorrectDigits(int[] code, int[] guess) {
    if (code.length != guess.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different lengths");
    }
    
    int correctDigits = 0;
    boolean[] used = new boolean[code.length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < code.length; j++) {
            if (guess[i] == code[j] && !used[j]) {
                correctDigits++;
                used[j] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return correctDigits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the for loop to iterate over the guess instead of iterate over the code array:

```
public static int getCorrectDigits(int[] code, int[] guess) {
    if (code.length != guess.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Different lengths");
    }

    int correctDigits = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < code.length; j++) {
            if (guess[i] == code[j]) {
                correctDigits++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return correctDigits;



    @Test
void ex1() {
    assertEquals(3, ArrayComp.getCorrectDigits(new int[] {5,9, 9, 9}, new int[] {0,9,9,9}));
}    @Test
void ex2() {
    assertEquals(2, ArrayComp.getCorrectDigits(new int[] {5,9, 9, 9}, new int[] {9,9,0,0}));
}    @Test
void ex3() {
    assertEquals(2, ArrayComp.getCorrectDigits(new int[] {5,9, 9, 9}, new int[] {0,0,9,9}));
}    @Test
void ex4() {
    assertEquals(1, ArrayComp.getCorrectDigits(new int[]{5, 9, 9, 9}, new int[]{9, 0, 0, 0}));
}
```

Comment: Your approach does raise the question of what is the expected result for `c={1,0,0,0}` and `g={1,1,1,1}` - is it 1 or 4?  Maybe @cymru_yesac could respond.

Comment: @Gardener c={1,0,0,0} and g={1,1,1,1}, result should be 1 (bc there's only one 1 in the code)